# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusBarNotification' of undefined

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using cordova 2.1.0, and am trying to add a notification to the status bar.

I'd included the related java files and js script into the project, and added the following line in the config.xml

```
<plugin name="StatusBarNotification" value="com.phonegap.plugins.statusBarNotification.StatusBarNotification"/>
```

In my html code, I'd added the following lines in my head tag

```
<script src="cordova-2.1.0.js"/>
<script src="statusbarnotification.js"/>
```

and at the bottom of the content div page, i'd added the following script

```
<script>
window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("Message Header", "Message details");
</script>
```

However when i run it in emulator for android 4.0, i'm hitting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusBarNotification' of undefined

Anyone has encounter this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my bad, it's a false alarm. I have the script file put into a js folder rather in the same folder as the cordova js file. After renaming the script src path to the correct one it is working now. Can't believe i spent few hours on this!!